# A limit about $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Here is my question:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^2\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{1+n}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]=?$$

Any hints will be fine. Thank you!

Comment: Try using the limit definition of $e$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that (to be made more rigorous)

- $(1+\frac{1}{1+n}) ^{n+1}=e^{(n+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{1+n}\right)}\sim e^{(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{1+n}-\frac{1}{2(1+n)^2}\right) }=e^{1-\frac{1}{2(1+n)}}\sim e\left(1-\frac{1}{2(1+n)}\right)$
- $(1+\frac{1}{n}) ^{n}=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\sim e^{n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right) }=e^{1-\frac{1}{2n}}\sim e\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$

then

$$n^2\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{1+n}\right)^{n+1} - \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]\sim e\cdot n^2\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2(1+n)}\right)=e\cdot n^2\left(\frac{2}{4n^2+4n}\right)$$

Comment: Upvoted. Your answer is better than mine.

Comment: @mickep Thanks, appreciate!

Comment: @gimusi Thanks!

Comment: @Yankai You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Here is "any" hint:

Set $x=1/n$ and you will have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x^2}\biggl(\Bigl(1+\frac{x}{1+x}\Bigr)^{1+1/x}-(1+x)^{1/x}\biggr).
$$
The expression
$$
\Bigl(1+\frac{x}{1+x}\Bigr)^{1+1/x}-(1+x)^{1/x}
$$
in the right-hand side can be expanded around $x=0$ (perhaps after defining it as $0$ at $x=0$).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use 
$$n^2\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{1+n}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right]=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{1+n}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}}{\frac1{n^2}}$$
and then use L'Hopital's Rule.